# Monitor not working

Tags: monitoring

I own a 3 year old Asus MX279H. So far working perfectly but the other day I saw the screen like flickering (was googling).

I tried changing the cable to the second HDMI, with other HDMI cable and on the VGA input. Everything was the same.

The next day I couldn't turn it on. Well, in fact I could but I could only see the led which was white (turned on) but if I try to select some inputs on the screen I can't see anything either. So no signal at all on the screen.

The power cable is an Asus one so I can't test it with another monitor but as long it has the led turned on I think is ok. What I tried was the other extension of the power cable (the one you need to connect to wall).

Also tried connection other laptops and it didn't work.

Need to say that the PC works without problems on another monitor that I've got (and using now).

So my question here is if I can fix this by myself.

Comment: Probably not - if you need to ask this question you almost certainly don't have the knowledge required.

Comment: I fix computers but never had to fix a monitor before. I'm quite sure that if I can point the problem out I could fix it ordering the pieces and replacing them

Comment: When you say you fix computers, do you mean you replace cards/discrete parts, or do you mean you desolder parts off the motherboard - because the latter is the level you will be working with in repairing a typical monitor.

Comment: Both. Do you haveany ideas about the issue?